# TFLearn (Tensor Flow) Shapes Modification from Base Tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

The TFLearn [Quickstart](http://tflearn.org/tutorials/quickstart.html) tutorial describes how to take data with 9 columns (2 of which get removed) and train the network. For the purposes of this question, let's call it 6 columns.

In the section "Building a Deep Neural Network", they have the following code

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

I would like to know the relationship between the numbers and the shape of the data.

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, columns])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, num1)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, num2)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, num3, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

In the code above, I have replaced the numbers in question with variables to aid with referencing.

I am assuming that columns is the actual number of culms in the data set.

The question comes up because I am trying to slightly modify their code with my own dataset as a learning opportunity.

In my dataset, I have a table of numbers `x` and `y` where y = 2*x.

The idea is that I would feed it a table of 1 to 100 of `x` values with its correct `y` value.

The idea is that then I can have it predict the output of `x=101` and hopefully it will return `y=202`.

In my code, I have the following

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 2])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(data, data, n_epoch=10, batch_size=10, show_metric=True)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 1) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

Comment: You have several things mixed up. 1. Split your data into features X and target values y. 2. Your input shape would than indeed be [None, 1]. 3. Don't use softmax activation for linear regression. 4. Use loss='mean_square' as argument in line 5 because the default loss is for multiple class classification. 5. Feed X, y to "fit" instead of data, data

Comment: Also look into the tflearn linear regression example https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/basics/linear_regression.py